# I want set variable to xml file in highrise api but it is not work. why?

Tags: php, xml, highrise

if i set static values in highrise like this:
    $person->setFirstName("XYZ");
    $person->setLastName("ABC");
    $person->addEmailAddress("example@gmail.com");

it add contact in highrise, but if i use variable instead of static values like this

```
 $person->setFirstName($fname);
 $person->setLastName($lname);
 $person->addEmailAddress($email);
```

I got this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'API for Person returned Status Code: 422 Expected Code: 201'

What is the problem .please help me any one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try passing the values in with quotes, like...

```
 $person->setFirstName("\"" . $fname . "\"" );
```

...also, did you check the email address was valid?